# Accessing a svn server across home network

Tags: apache, networking, svn

I have setup subversion (used svn-1.4.6-setup.exe from subversion.tigris.org ) with Apache server on my local machine.

Apache's http.conf has the following which I suppose is needed for the svn configuration;

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module "C:/Program Files/Subversion/bin/mod_dav_svn.so"
LoadModule authz_svn_module "C:/Program Files/Subversion/bin/mod_authz_svn.so"

<Location /project1>
DAV svn
SVNPath "C:/svn_repositories/project1"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repository"
AuthUserFile "c:/svn_conf/project1/passwd"
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I am able to create repositories and checkout ( with tortoiseSVN ) on the same machine with  **file:///absolute-path-to-svn-repository.**  I want to be able to access the repositories from the other machines connected to the network(the internet network at home).

I tried checking out from other machines with the url **svn://IP-address/project1** , it didn't work. Shows the following message;

**Error: Can't connect to host {IP-address}: A connection attempt failed because the

Error: connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established

Error: connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**

If I try to access with **http://IP-address/project1** , it prompts for the login but it doesn't get past that. I believe I am entering the correct login. The error message is;

**Couldn't open the svn repository.**

Any idea what could be wrong?. Thanks!.

Comment: Sounds like the firewall on the repo machine may be blocking inbound traffic

Comment: @Michael. I tried checking out from another machine turning off the wirefall (on windows 7) on both the machines, still the same result.

Comment: Firewall should not be an issue if you are using Apache with http:// (one of the benefits), but if you use svnserve with svn:// you might need to open the ports for the svn protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your subversion server to accept connections over the SVN protocol? On a linux system you would run the svnserve daemon (something like svnserve -d). You may also need to open SVN ports in your firewall (unless the svn server is on your local machine).

Answer (score 1):

You use the svn:// protocol when using svnserve.
If you want to use Apache, you should be using http://.

I'm not familiar with configuration for Apache with svn, but I would guess that your config file is not quite correct.

[Choosing a server configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) <- start here

Also: [Basic Apache Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)